# Emails sent returning 'Queue Expired' error.

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am getting this error when trying to send mail from the mail server using php only for certain email addresses.

Is this related to spam being blocked by the recipient mail system ? 
Or any clue on what is this problem due to ?

```
Remote Server returned '550 4.4.7 QUEUE.Expired; message expired in unreachable destination queue. Reason: A matching connector cannot be found to route the external recipient'
```

Below are the port details.

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;
```

Answer (score 1):

Queue expiry is usually caused by delivery deferrals or the destination mail server being down. It is generated by your local mail server after you've given it a message to deliver, not PHPMailer, so it has nothing to do with the ports or any other PHPMailer settings.